# how to add a TagBuilder to View when loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to add an option tag using TagBuilder. But I can't figure how to write the tagbuilder to the View.

Code:

```
@foreach (IActivityType at in _data.Context.ActivityType)
{
    TagBuilder opt = new TagBuilder("option");
    opt.Attributes.Add("value", at.Id.ToString());

    if (at.Id.Equals(activity.ActivityTypeId))
    {
        opt.Attributes.Add("selected", "selected");
    }

    @Html.Raw(opt);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
@Html.Raw(opt.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
```

PS: You may need to use `SetInnerText()` with `option` tag

Please also keep in mind that the preferable approach is to **create custom HTML Helper** and use it accordingly. [Check This Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs#creating-an-image-html-helper)

Comment: I was looking to avoid creating tag helper since this its just one time I need this. But yeah, I could be easily done with tag helpers

Comment: no it couldn't find a ToString method that takes a TagRenderMode and returns html. But I made an extension that return the tag as html. I'll update the question. Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

So ended up with a great little solution with an IHtmlContent extension that return a tag as html.

```
public static string ToZtring(this IHtmlContent content, bool encode = false)
{
    string result = default;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        content.WriteTo(sw, HtmlEncoder.Default);

        result = sw.ToString();
    }

    if (!encode)
    {
        result = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(result);
    }

    return result;
}

TagBuilder opt = new TagBuilder("option");
opt.Attributes.Add("value", "demo");

@Html.Raw(opt.ToZtring());
```

I called the extension method for ToZstring() to avoid naming issues with ToString()

Answer (score 0):

I'm migrating a site to .NET6 and the solution there is to use the @ followed by the TagBuilder object's name : -

```
@foreach (IActivityType at in _data.Context.ActivityType)
{
    TagBuilder opt = new TagBuilder("option");
    
    // ...

    @opt // <-- This renders opt to the View.
}
```